Problem with anchor build, says my active rustc version is 1.68.0-dev when it is actually 1.81.0
I wrote a small game in Rust, a Solana based game and when I try to run anchor build I keep getting this error:
➜  rps-game git:(main) anchor build
error: package `solana-program v1.18.23` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.75.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.68.0-dev
Either upgrade to rustc 1.75.0 or newer, or use
cargo update -p solana-program@1.18.23 --precise ver
where `ver` is the latest version of `solana-program` supporting rustc 1.68.0-dev
➜  rps-game git:(main) rustc --version
rustc 1.81.0 (eeb90cda1 2024-09-04)

My rust-toolchain.toml in my root
[toolchain]
channel = "1.81.0"
components = ["rustfmt", "clippy"]

My programs/rps-game/src/Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "rps-game"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Created with Anchor"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]
name = "rps_game"

[features]
default = []
cpi = ["no-entrypoint"]
no-entrypoint = []
no-idl = []
no-log-ix-name = []

[dependencies]
solana-program = "1.17.0"
anchor-lang = "0.29.0"

More versions
➜  rps-game git:(main) rustc --version
rustc 1.81.0 (eeb90cda1 2024-09-04)
➜  rps-game git:(main) anchor --version
anchor-cli 0.29.0
➜  rps-game git:(main) solana --version
solana-cli 1.17.0 (src:660e41a8; feat:2241946265, client:SolanaLabs)
➜  rps-game git:(main) cargo --version
cargo 1.81.0 (2dbb1af80 2024-08-20)
➜  rps-game git:(main) 


Did you build it by any chance the first time with an older version? Maybe try cargo update oder remove your Cargo.lock.
